# What is the meaning of 屏幕前的你?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> 曾有朋友戏称，脱发已经成为了当代青少年担忧的最大问题！**屏幕前的你**，是否也在感概”头发都去哪儿了“？

I don't understand what 屏幕前的你 means. 屏幕 means "screen", but then I don't understand the part 前的你.

So what does the phrase and the whole sentence mean and how does it work grammatically?

Comment: you who are in front of the (e.g.TV) screen, 屏幕前 used attributively to 你

Comment: see more examples of 的+人称代词 （的＋personal pronoun), feed 的我／你／他／她／我们／你们／他们／她们 ichacha, 部份的我    part of me
超码的我    super size me
痴心的我    devoted to you,  some grammars say this use is restricted to literary language, but the present example may show that it can be used colloquially (humourously ?)

Comment: @user6065 So does the 你 refer to the reader, or the 当代青少年 as the user "dan" explained in the answer?

Comment: comment #2 refers to the literal meaning (disregarding context) and "how does it work grammatically". Why not ask the same question of the other user answering the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 屏幕前的你

你 here refers to people in general. In this context, it refers to 当代青少年, the youth of today.

So, here 屏幕前的你 could be translated to *the youth of today who are still sitting in front of screens*.

屏幕前的你，是否也在感概”头发都去哪儿了“？: *For those youth of today, who are still sitting in front of screens, are you still sighing with emotions and thinking "where your hair has gone?"*

Answer (score 2):

### 屏幕前的你

Split it like this: 屏幕 前 的 你

```
屏幕：Screen
前：before
```

屏幕前 means "before the screen".

This means that 'The one (you) on the other side the screen'.

The sentence seems to be in an advertisement.
Translation:

Some friends (of the speaker) joked about baldness being the most worrying problem among adolescents.  And are you, who are on the other side of the screen, also worrying about where have your hairs went?

Answer (score 0):

This picture tells the story. 体会体会。

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means *the man who is in front of the screen*.

屏目前的 is objective, represents a state, different from the state of being face to face.